# How to drive atomizer?

Tags: piezo, sine

I'm trying to build my own diffuser with a piezo atomizer. I'm new to electrical engineering and don't really know what I'm doing. Reading the specs for the atomizer from the [description](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2251832661951856.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.0.0.21ef1802Dpk346&gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt) it says:

- Driving Voltage: DC 3-12 V
- Power: 1.5-3 W
- Frequency: 113+/-3 kHz

Does that mean that I need a sine wave with Vrms between 3 & 12 V, a freq of 113 kHz that draws around 200 milliamps? I pulled this sine wave from a commercial diffuser, would it work for the atomizer I selected?

[image: commercial sine wave]

I haven't built a sine wave generator yet because I don't know what kind of values I need, but any suggestions for where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The "spec" of a **DC** power supply, coupled with the "USB" in the product description, implies to me that this device has an oscillator built-in and all you need to do is power it. However, given the place you're sourcing it from: buyer-beware applies ...

Comment: @brhans I was just writing that exact comment including the "buyer beware" part, but you beat me to it!

Comment: I haven’t been able to find any other atomizers from like mouser. I got the parts and they are just the atomizer, no additional circuitry.

Comment: VRMS = VAC, so the oscilloscope is showing 4.3VAC at 757kHz.  That is over six times faster than this model's spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photo shows just the atomizer piezo element. To drive it, typical boards like [this](https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_9g1x7j) one:
[image]

.. use an inductor with the element, driven with an N-channel MOSFET such as [AO3400](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/ao3400.pdf).

The 113kHz +/-3kHz square wave drive for the MOSFET is generated by a simple MCU with internal RC oscillator, which is the easiest way to get an inexpensive and relatively accurate oscillator without adjustment. Perhaps one like [this](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108181830_Shenzhen-Fuman-Elec-XMC8P53S8_C2840140.pdf) OTP MCU which has +/-1% ~+/-2.5% oscillator accuracy.

The ~800kHz from your driver board is outside the spec for the element, so it won't drive them effectively (away from the element's mechanical resonance frequency) and may damage the driver or the element. It is designed to produce relatively small droplets compared to the element you have.

Comment: Thanks. Any reason for a square wave vs other wave forms?

Comment: It's simple (and the switching of the MOSFET will be on/off so very efficient, that's the only reason they can use an SOT23 MOSFET rather than something with a heatsink). The waveform across the piezo will be more like a sine wave due to the inductor.

Comment: Would something like this work? Other than that circuit has a VCC of 15v. https://www.instructables.com/Make-Your-Own-Super-Simple-Ultrasonic-Mist-Maker/

Comment: Yes (from skimming that video anyway). With a 555 you'd want to trim the frequency to get reasonably close to the ideal frequency. Since 100kHz is up near the maximum frequency for some variants it will likely need trimming to get within a few percent.

Answer (score 1):

The [cited webpage](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32848266608.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.0.0.21ef1802Dpk346&gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt) says

> 2.Driving Voltage:DC 3-12V

This strongly indicates that you need only provide a DC voltage in the 3 to 12 VDC range.

IF it in fact requires AC (which MAY be the case for products on AliEWxpress sites) then you (probably) need 3-12V RMS drive at 113+/-3KHz.

Start with say 5V DC - which is unlikely to do any harm and which should work.